# gpg -d hangs while decrypting

Tags: fedora, encryption, gpg

i have a key installed on my fedora 35. i see that the subkey for encryption is active and unexpired. i can encrypt with it just fine but when i try to decrypt, it just hangs. though `echo 'encrypt this'|gpg --encrypt -r {5FFFF8846A5AAAA3....} --armor` results in a well formed output `echo 'encrypt this'|gpg --encrypt -r {5FFFF8846A5AAAA3....} --armor|gpg -d -vvv` hangs like the following with scdaemon process constantly above 99% of cpu usage

```
gpg: using character set 'utf-8'
gpg: Note: RFC4880bis features are enabled.
gpg: armor: BEGIN PGP MESSAGE
# off=0 ctb=85 tag=1 hlen=3 plen=524
:pubkey enc packet: version 3, algo 1, keyid 5FFFF8846A5AAAA3
    data: [4093 bits]
gpg: public key is 5FFFF8846A5AAAA3
# off=527 ctb=d2 tag=18 hlen=2 plen=70 new-ctb
:encrypted data packet:
    length: 70
    mdc_method: 2
gpg: using subkey 5FFFF8846A5AAAA3 instead of primary key 4223338D9E661ECF
gpg: encrypted with rsa4096 key, ID 5FFFF8846A5AAAA3, created 2021-12-12
      "a<a@b.com>"
```

any idea how i can troubleshoot this issue? many thanks in advance!

**update**: i added `disable-scdaemon` to gpg-agent.conf file and restarted it. it appears to solve the issue with this workaround. i am wondering if there is a more permanent solution than this.